# Error while Installing TestNG Eclipse Plugin 6.14.3 Version

Tags: selenium, eclipse-plugin, testng, eclipse-jdt, testng-eclipse

I am getting the following error while installing TestNG plugin( 6.14.3) in Eclipse.

> Missing requirement: TestNG Eclipse Support 6.14.3.201902250526
>   (org.testng.eclipse 6.14.3.201902250526) requires 'bundle
>   org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.10.0' but it could not be found Cannot
>   satisfy dependency: From: TestNG 6.14.3.201902250526
>   (org.testng.eclipse.feature.group 6.14.3.201902250526) To:
>   org.testng.eclipse [6.14.3.201902250526]

I am using Eclipse Oxygen- March Edition. Could anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version on Eclipse (Oxygen) is too old for that version of TestNG.

Version 3.10.0 of org.eclipse.jdt.launching was not introduced until Eclipse Photon so you need at least that version of Eclipse, but preferably the current version (Eclipse 2018-12 at time time of writing)

Answer (score 0):

We had same issue for several employees. In our case it doesn't relate to Eclipse version.
Seems as new WebSense antivirus blocked the installation of the TestNG from default location. Eclipse showed the error from the description and continued to look for "alternative solution" which took many hours, but finally TestNG was installed successfully. Just have patience. Or try to disable antivirus.

[let process to continue in spite of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plKxO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Greg and Ilana.
TestNG installed successfully when the Eclipse was updated to 2018-12 Version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue while installing TestNG in Eclipse version there are few simple steps to follow:

1. Download zipped latest version of Eclipse from below location (http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/)
2. Store it your drive (zipped folder suppose in C drive)
3. After that go to Eclipse and install new software, click on add, archive, and complete the installation by selecting Next option when prompted)
4. Restart Eclipse you will see TestNG option in there.

Answer (score 0):

while installing from add new software ,there is an option to check for solution rather than default selection. Please select different version of TestNG  which is compatible with your eclipse version .This solution worked for me while using eclipse Mars(4.5.2)