# unable to install TestNg in Eclipse getting errror like"Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i have tried to install TestNG in these ways:

1: Help>> install new software>> work with>> http://beust.com/eclipse/enter
Or use this http://dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/

2: Help >> Eclipse MarketPlace >> Search for TestNG

after while getting an error like

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: TestNG M2E (Maven) Integration (Optional) 7.3.0.202008060412 (org.testng.eclipse.maven.feature.feature.group 7.3.0.202008060412)

Missing requirement: TestNG Eclipse Support 7.3.0.202008060412 (org.testng.eclipse 7.3.0.202008060412) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.10.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: TestNG 7.3.0.202008060412 (org.testng.eclipse.feature.group 7.3.0.202008060412)
    To: org.testng.eclipse [7.3.0.20200806041
```

Comment: can anybody help

Comment: anybody help me to resolve this error.

Comment: can anybody help..

Comment: can anybody help..

Comment: u there???????.

Comment: This error come when eclipse and TestNG are not compatible. Kindly refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910581/error-while-installing-testng-eclipse-plugin-6-14-3-version) SO post for help. You need to upgrade your eclipse to resolve issue.